# Laravel Mix IE11 Babel Issues

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, laravel-mix

I'm currently trying to install Laravel Mix inside a WordPress project to handle my asset compilation.

I have my `webpack.mix.js` file set up as follows:

```
let mix = require("laravel-mix");

mix.babel("src/js/app.js", "dist/js/app.js")
    .sass("src/scss/style.scss", "dist/css/style.css")
    .sourceMaps()
    .setPublicPath("dist");
```

I also have a `.babelrc` set up as follows:

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/preset-env",
            {
                "targets": {
                    "ie": "11"
                }
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The only code I'm currently using inside `app.js` is this:

`import Vue from "vue";`

However, when I go to the page I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:3`

And file compiled looks like this (the issue apparently lies on the `var _vue` line):

```
"use strict";

var _vue = _interopRequireDefault(require("vue"));

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

I'm really stuck on this issue as I'm unsure what to do. Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: During production complication, it may output two files called `manifest.js` and `vendor.js` depend on how your mix is setuped.  You probably want to include those two files before `app.js` because that's where it store webpack require method and other/external vendors javascript.

Comment: @Noogen I've set up Laravel Mix exactly how the docs suggest. I have no idea where this is coming from and manifest.js has no reference to the error.